# What are the AccessorGetter and AccessorSetter typedefs for in v8?

Tags: c++, v8

I am viewing v8 header file, and got a problem again.

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/v8/include/v8.h#L1408-1414

```
typedef Handle<Value> (*AccessorGetter)(Local<String> property,
                                    const AccessorInfo& info);


typedef void (*AccessorSetter)(Local<String> property,
                           Local<Value> value,
                           const AccessorInfo& info);
```

I don't know what this typedef use for?

Comment: These are two `typedef` that define types _pointer-to-a-function_: `AccessorGetter` and `AccessorSetter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two type definitions create simple names for pointers to functions matching a given signature.

```
typedef Handle<Value> (*AccessorGetter)
    (Local<String> property,
     const AccessorInfo& info);
```

This defines a new type `AccessorGetter` that can be used to create variables that contain the address of a function with the signature

```
Handle<Value> SampleAccessorGetter
    (Local<String> property,
     const AccessorInfo& info)
{
    // ...
}
```

And it can be used in code such as:

```
int main ()
{
    // two variables that contain the address of `SampleAccessorGetter`.
    AccessorGetter f = &SampleAccessorGetter;
    AccessorGetter g = &SampleAccessorGetter;

    // these variables can be used to call the pointee function:
    f(...);
    g(...);
}
```

Comment: The 1st `()` is expression, the 2nd `()` means function, right?

Answer (score 0):

`AccessorGetter` and `AccessorSetter` are function pointer types that take the arguments on the right and have the return type on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Those are defining function pointer types.

The first declares the type `AccessorGetter` to be a pointer to a function that takes two arguments, a `Local<String>` and a `const AccessorInfo&`, and returns a `Handle<Value>`.

The second declares the type `AccessorSetter` to be a pointer to a function taking three values (`Local<String>, Local<Value>, and const AccessorInfo&`) and returning nothing (`void`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a function pointer:
Handle (*AccessorGetter)(Local property, const AccessorInfo& info);

This is typedef for this kind of function pointer:
typedef Handle (*AccessorGetter)(Local property, const AccessorInfo& info);